# Wordpress how to check if a post is the first post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using the `get_previous_post()` to check if the first custom post type so I can add a condition. It works if it's not equal to 0 (the first post), to make it work I need to parse the output.

The following didn't work, I get the error Argument ($str) must be of type string

```
$checkFirst = get_previous_post();
<?php !(wp_parse_str(strlen($checkFirst)) == 0) ? 'something' : '';?>
```

I have also tried :

```
wp_parse_str(strlen($checkFirst), $output)
<?php !($output[strlen($checkFirst)] == 0) ? 'something' : '';?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think you need to parse it?

According to the [`get_previous_post`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_previous_post/#return), it returns:

- Null if global $post is not set.
- Empty string if no corresponding post exists.
- Post object if the current post is not the first one.

So you could check its value like this:

```php
$checkFirst = get_previous_post();

echo $checkFirst  
               ? 'There is a previous post' 
               : 'No, this is the first post';
```

You don't need to use `strlen` or `wp_parse_str`.